# Firefox add-on Action Button has no icon

Tags: firefox-addon-sdk

I added this code to my Add-on SDK extension in the index.js:

```
var button = ActionButton({
  id: "my-button",
  label: "my button",
  icon: {
    "16": "./us16.png",
    "32": "./us32.png"
  },
  onClick: firstClick
});
```

The Action Button gets added just fine and works, but there is no icon showing. I put the two icon files in the root folder of my add-on. Should I have put them elsewhere?

([Button documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/ui_button_action).)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Put your icons in `data` folder, whilst leaving the paths in the code as they are now.

Comment: Fantastic! Do you also happen to know where this is documented?

Comment: Sure! Actually you can find it in the piece of documentation you provided by link - under `Globals -> Constructors -> Parameters` section.

Comment: I have just checked and the `data` folder doesn't even have to exist, as long as you suppose it exists, and use path relative to it `'./../us16.png'` (when placing `us16.png` in main add-on directory).

Answer (score 2):

I have same problem. And solution is add this code to packet.json
"permissions": {"private-browsing": true}

see here [Firefox SDK Sample Add On Exported XPI Action Button Doesn't Show Up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25319522/firefox-sdk-sample-add-on-exported-xpi-action-button-doesnt-show-up?rq=1)